# Convert particle system wont work properly : it modifies the geometry

Tags: modifiers, particles, baking

I have a problem with the "Convert" button of my particle system : as soon as I click on the Convert button of the particles system modifier, my particles losses a part of their geometry (it is more rounded)

Here is the story (Apologizes if my english is hard to understand, I'm french, baguette) : **I'm making asteroids belts**.

So, I've created rocks affected by a subdivision modifier and a displace modifier with voronoi texture. Then I've duplicated it and scaled the rocks differently. Then, I've created a collection to put my rocks in.

Then I created a simple torus on which my rocks poped up thanks to a particle system. It is set as this :
[image: Particle System settings (1 by torus, so 1 by asteroid belt]

**I have plenty of particles system as this one, now I need to "bake" this into meshes** (1 asteroid belt = 1 mesh).

To do that, here are my steps :

1. Select Torus 1 (first particle system, first belt)
2. Hit the Convert button on the Particle system modifier
3. Object -> Relation -> Make Single User (Object & Data) so that every particle became the single user of its modifiers (the subdivision and displace modifiers inherited from the rocks i've created earlier as a source collection for my particle system)
4. Object -> Convert to -> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text
5. Ctr-J : Now I have a unique mesh for the first asteroids belt (then I decimate it but anyway)

**My problem is : Once I clicked on the convert button of a particle system, every rocks loses a part of its geometry, like if the Voronoi Texture used for the displace modifier losen its effect.**

[image: A particle BEFORE applying the Particle system with the convert button]

[image: Particle after hitting the convert button]

How can I fix that ? I really need a strong texture for my scene.

*By the way, the rock texture is just a noise node plugged in a bump node, then in the Normal input of a principled BSDF. So the displace modifier of a rock applies a Voronoi texture on it, then I bump the texture with a noise texture.*

Comment: Which texture coordinates input are you using?

Comment: It is a simple texture coordinate node (Object output) plugged in a mapping node (Vector input). Then mapping node -> noise texture.

But again, is it a texture problem ? For me it is more about geometry, as my texture only applies a bump on the mesh.

In any case, I use the Texture coordinate + Mapping with pretty every texture I use. I'm a begginer, I usually use it to coordinate a texture with a UV Map. In this case I don't really think it is usefull but I put it anyway...

Here's a screen of the texture : https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2020/09/01/200901054102901069.png

Comment: ok, is the displacement modifier set to global coordinates or local? I presume this is global... Set it to local. Because when applyed, the relative size is totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the particles are converted, they aquire their size as particle, so generally much smaller than the original object.

From that, if the displacement is set to *"global"* coordinates, the mapping of the object on the voronoi texture becomes very small and so has few variations.

As solution, set the displacement to *"local"* coordinates and the mapping will be equivalent between your original objects and the converted particles.

[image]

Alternatively, you can change (lower) the voronoi texture size once the particles are converted.

Comment: Ok it worked like a charm !! Sorry for my past comment I didnt know that you were asking for the Text Coordinate setting in the displace modifier haha

I had to set this setting to Local for every rock references (29 haha...) and then modify the Voronoi Texture used for the displace modifier, as it gave me a slighty rounder displacement with this "Local" setting, as you said. But after this, Blender managed to convert those particles in a mesh that is perfectly the same !

Thank you ! :)